# Unregistering a token in the Parity Token Registry

Tags: parity, dapps, tokens

I am curious how to remove a token from the token registry in Parity. It is a token I have listed myself, and I am using the same address to try unregistering it.

I am using MyEtherWallet to send transactions, and the only piece of data I have to input for the transaction is the ID number for the listing (and I know I'm supplying the correct ID number).

When I look at my transaction on Etherscan, it clearly went through but there are no event logs or bad jump destination errors or anything like that.

What could I be doing wrong? And is there a place I can go to get better details on how to use the token registry dapp generally?

Comment: You can probably get a quicker answer on the Parity gitter channel. Welcome to the Ethereum stack exchange.

Comment: So what is your question exactly? You could also use parity directly and just use the "Unregister" button in the UI.

Comment: Where is the "unregister" button? When I switch to the listing owner address as my primary wallet and go into the token registry, the only extra button I see on my token is the "add meta-data" button. Perhaps I need to go to a different page to see the unregister button?

Comment: Please, get on https://gitter.im/paritytech/parity - we can sort that for you.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is all sorted. Apparently there is no way for someone to take down a listing they made, and it can only be done by someone in control of the registry contract itself.

Thanks everyone for giving answers!